# Creating a new different container for every client connecting to a server - Devops engineering

Tags: docker, containers, devops, load-balancing, sticky-session

How to configure a server using nginx (or something else) that only one client can have session with the server at the same time?

Each client has his own server container and the session is sticky and multiple clients doesn't share same server container.

All client-server I manage them and they run on a private VC , so I have full control on them , for example I can do that before client starts session with server they will send a message to the controller component (if it can help for the solution)

I tried using ngnix reverse proxy with sticky session - but many clients are in the same server, and there is no option to delete the container when the session is ended.